# Collapse/minimize window to task pane. How to correctly name this action?

Tags: word-request

How to name action that is produced when clicking the button on window that collapses/minimizes it to the task pane?

[image: Windows minimze button]

Comment: You should use the standard term used by the operating system. In the case of Microsoft Windows, it is *minimize*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also suggest to use "minimize":

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/minimize

There is no sense to use any other word / name, because this is something like a standard.

Comment: There is no sense in using. Not to use.